# The address of dereferenced array doesn't match the address of array element

Tags: c, pointers

As mentioned in the code comments, when I try to find the address of a dereferenced array, it varies from the address that I get directly from the array.

```
int main()
{
    double disp[1][2][2] = {{
        {10, 11},
        {14, 15}}
    };

    for(int i = 0 ; i < 4 ; ++i){
           printf("%d ", &(((double *)disp)[i]));
           printf("%f ", (((double *)disp)[i]));
           //Here it give -1532765552 as address of value 10.000000
    }

    //but here it give -1532765552 as the address of 15.000000  
    printf("\n%d ", &(*disp));
    printf("\n%f ", (*disp));


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What's with the weird casts? What are you trying to do?

Comment: `%d` and `%f` are no valid format modifiers for pointers; use `%p`.

Comment: @ensc 0x7ffd7d823320 10.000000 and 0x7ffd7d823320 15.000000, it gives same address for different values.

Comment: the last 2 printf statements dereference an array, which results in the first element (in this case the first row), which is the address of 10, not 15. The results are not conflicting in terms of the addresses (but your printf format specifiers are wrong).

Comment: `printf("\n%f ", (*disp));` here `*disp` is a pointer and you're printing it as a `double`, which causes UB. Do you have compiler warnings enabled?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat No, I'm using an online compiler

Comment: Then use a compiler that you can configure properly, explain why you think you should be printing the address of the element with value 15, and tell us _what you are trying to do_.

Comment: @StephenPhilip Here you go: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8492d819bcb2d0ea

Comment: @Ruks That's not a dynamic allocation, if that's what you mean?

Comment: @Ruks Not sure what you're referring to?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I'm using this code to access a multidimensional array sequentially. my doubt is, why does (*var) gives me the last element of that array?.

Comment: No, that's how you're trying to _achieve_ your goal. What is your goal?

Comment: Sorry, I've done accessing using the first part of the code. while I was trying to compare the pointer to an array it gives the last element in the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because the `*disp` has the type of `double[2][2]` and `*(double *)disp` has a type of `double` even if the addresses are the same. So the `printf("\n%f ", (*disp));` is an undefined behavior

```
int main()
{
    double disp[1][2][2] = {{
        {10, 11},
        {14, 15}}
    };

    for(int i = 0 ; i < 4 ; ++i){
           printf("%p ", (void *)&(((double *)disp)[i]));
           printf("%f \n", (((double *)disp)[i]));
           //Here it give -1532765552 as address of value 10.000000
    }

    //but here it give -1532765552 as the address of 15.000000  
    printf("\n%p ", (void *)&(*disp));
    printf("%f \n", *(double *)disp);
    printf("\n%p ", (void *)&(*disp));
    printf("%f \n", *disp[0][0]);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `%p` expects a `void *`, so that should be `(void *)&(((double *)disp)[i])`, `(void *)&(*disp)`, etc.

Comment: @melpomene it is actually a minor problem here. The answer is about the *types*. This may be an UB on the systems where pointers of different types are different. None of the machines used by the SO users has different pointer representation for the different types